# log-transform in ggplot producing NaNs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I hope you're doing well.

I'm trying to produce a log-scale transformed figure in R using ggplot, and when I plot the standard deviations, it produces NaNs.

To start, here's a minimum reproducible example of my dataset:

```
PARstackoversubset <- structure(list(avg_time = structure(c(1547618400, 1547704800, 
1547791200, 1547877600, 1547964000, 1548050400, 1548136800, 1548223200, 
1548309600, 1548396000, 1548482400, 1548568800, 1548655200, 1548741600, 
1548828000, 1548914400, 1549000800, 1549087200, 1549173600, 1549260000, 
1549346400, 1549432800, 1549519200, 1549605600, 1549692000, 1549778400, 
1549864800, 1549951200, 1550037600, 1550124000, 1550210400, 1550296800, 
1550383200, 1550469600, 1550556000, 1550642400, 1550728800, 1550815200, 
1550901600, 1550988000, 1551074400, 1551160800, 1551247200, 1551333600
), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Mean = c(0.0876461991134144, 
0.0944408198406377, 0.096038935136038, 0.0948305263356754, 0.0967162678403481, 
0.0984582303708988, 0.100171845626728, 0.102676475590823, 0.104571388951652, 
0.10882746610175, 0.115720996556773, 0.113705359003861, 0.120095336695858, 
0.126049113018388, 0.129585507558475, 0.134126658371055, 0.1401536636013, 
0.142923427448137, 0.141473684896322, 0.145930739610101, 0.150224401217076, 
0.161706107817229, 0.184366041466597, 0.180008270126198, 0.162907721209955, 
0.138055425207523, 0.145033685101522, 0.162280006497285, 0.165496068128912, 
0.181153940939556, 0.19899968645021, 0.214597047778313, 0.232410292629363, 
0.237446301786995, 0.249145603941397, 0.251678189666611, 0.269608276696466, 
0.264283151355829, 0.294340663241422, 0.299557139647019, 0.293329194353745, 
0.263624839483696, 0.262211585350154, 0.285372040766518), StdDev = c(0.0232128502305939, 
0.0395795501752494, 0.0411072234355152, 0.0389622908914935, 0.0431928266587485, 
0.047983828098703, 0.0520247774822332, 0.0564883000654964, 0.0601212997845338, 
0.0693008550674333, 0.0826023152055433, 0.076813683198804, 0.0910210932121596, 
0.102631271495977, 0.109368323966347, 0.117266902195709, 0.122871912515675, 
0.140451039535823, 0.143219460325224, 0.151207636468757, 0.156010433039491, 
0.176721322590358, 0.217193943711736, 0.207112475019577, 0.174706342538407, 
0.121928151509366, 0.132499799522759, 0.169579624744958, 0.173370790336754, 
0.19339994145002, 0.22550846187337, 0.251871153554344, 0.281059504677826, 
0.285926022881983, 0.302692606424712, 0.295328672923439, 0.347065933278786, 
0.309911530590257, 0.36374175468549, 0.373315008167889, 0.345560204541572, 
0.302468983443347, 0.298324002426436, 0.333451615024357)), row.names = c(NA, 
-44L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The time series data is daily and only a portion of a dataset for many months, with a mean column and a standard deviation column. To generate the ggplot figure, I used this code:

```
ggplot(data = PARstackoversubset, mapping = aes(x=avg_time)) + geom_line(mapping = aes(y=Mean), linewidth=1, color = "black") + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Mean-StdDev, ymax=Mean+StdDev), alpha = 0.3) + scale_y_log10(expand = c(0,0)) + ylab(bquote('PAR ('*'μmol' ~photons~ m^-2~s^-1*')')) + theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.background = element_blank(),plot.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +  scale_x_datetime(limits = as.POSIXct(c('2019-01-16','2019-02-28')), expand = c(0,0),labels = date_format("%b"), date_breaks = "1 month", name = "Date")
```

I believe the problem comes from how `scale_y_log10` interacts with `geom_ribbon`, as these are the warnings I received:

```
Warning messages:
1: In self$trans$transform(x) : NaNs produced
2: Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis
```

I'm using `geom_ribbon` to show the standard deviations, however when subtracting the mean by the standard deviation to use `ymin`, or the same for `ymax`, I believe generates negative values that can then not be applied when log transforming the y-axis.

Is there any way around this? I need the y-axis to be log-transformed to base 10, and I have to show those standard deviations around the mean. Maybe there's a geom that doesn't require the `ymin` and `ymax` format I used?

Thank you for your time, I sincerely appreciate any efforts you may provide to help me figure this out.

Comment: A simple way would be to set a minimum threshold, like `ymin = pmax(1e-6, Mean-StdDev)`. The issue is that this is arbitrary - you're picking the low value, which is a bit misleading. If you care about that, it's a methods problem - you should perhaps try to model and develop confidence intervals on the log scale.